# JS Proxy intercept keys and nested keys doesn't return the fallback value

Tags: javascript, proxy

I have an object that I want to intercept access to any of its properties, and if it does not exists to return a fallback value. I tried the following implementation, but for some reason, I get back a `Proxy` object instead of the fallback value.

```js
const isObject = obj => typeof obj === 'object';
const hasKey = (obj, key) => key in obj;
const isNullOrUndefined = obj => obj === null || obj === undefined;

const obj = {
  keyOne: ''
};


const returnPropertyOnObject = (target, property) => {
  if (isObject(target[property])) {
    return safe(target[property])
  }

  return target[property];
}

function safe(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, property) => {

      if (hasKey(target, property) && !isNullOrUndefined(target[property])) {
        returnPropertyOnObject(target, property)
      }

      return new Proxy({}, {
        get: function(target, property) {
          return 'MISSING!!';
        }
      });;
    }
  });
}

const wrap = safe(obj);

console.log(wrap.notExists);
console.log(wrap.notExists.deep.nested.nested);
```

Moreover, I sometimes get properties like `toJSON`, or `toString` inside the Proxy.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you return `missing` from the inner proxy, the chain is broken and the next dot will return bare `undefined`. You have to return the stub object itself from its `get`. To provide a default value, override `toPrimitive`:

```js
undef = new Proxy({}, {
    get(_, prop) {
        // support some standard object methods, feel free to add more
        
        if (prop === Symbol.toPrimitive)
            return () => 'no such thing'
        if (prop === 'toString')
            return () => 'whatever you want'
        if (prop === 'toJSON')
            return () => 'whatever you want'

        // if asked for a custom prop, return itself
        
        return undef;
    }
});


const safe = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, property) {
        let v = target[property];

        if (v === null || typeof v === 'undefined')
            return undef;

        if (typeof v === 'object')
            return safe(v);

        return v;
    }
});

const wrap = safe({foo: {bar: 'hey'}});

console.log(wrap.foo.bar + "!");
console.log(wrap.notExists.xx.yy.zz + "!");
```

> Symbol.toPrimitive is a symbol that specifies a function... called to convert an object to a corresponding primitive value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive

Comment: But how can I return a default value?

Comment: Cool. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @undefined: added the doc link. Essentially, it's the same as old-style toString/valueOf thing.

Comment: But why it throws when I try to call toString? wrap.foo.bar.toString()

Comment: yep, this is because `undef.get` returns `undef` itself for all props, including `toString`. If you want `undef` to have standard object methods, you have to include them in `get`, like we did with `Symbol.toPrimitive`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how. You are returning a function. Please, add an example for this and I will accept the answer. Thank you very much!